# applying an object with a ICollection<Enum> type

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

In an ASP.NET 3.1 CORE project, using EF, I am trying to implement an object that holds a type of `ICollection<Enum> type`.

the problem is after reading some tutorials and trying to migrate it to my database something seems off, I will attach screenshots and code for more understanding.

this is the object class :

```
public class UsersCredentialsModel
{
    [Key]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ServiceModel> Services { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

The ServiceModel class:

```
 public class ServiceModel
 {
    [Key]
    public string ServiceId { get; set; }
    public Service Service { get; set; }
 }
```

The Service Enum Class:

```
 public enum Service : int
 {
    Badoo = 0,
    Tinder = 1,
    Grinder = 2,
    OkCupid = 3
 }
```

This is the AppDbContext class:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { 
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Message>().Property(m => m.Service).HasConversion<int>();
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<Message>(m => m.Messages).WithOne(u => 
        u.User).IsRequired();
        builder.Entity<ServiceModel>().Property(m => m.Service).HasConversion<int>();
        builder.Entity<UsersCredentialsModel>().HasMany(s => s.Services);


        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }

    public DbSet<UsersCredentialsModel> UsersCredentialsModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceModel> ServiceModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CookieModel> CookieModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectionModel> ProjectionModel { get; set; }

 }
```

This is a picture of the UsersCredentialsModel database schema:

[image]

** I believe that there should be a filed called "ServiceId" corresponding to the Id of the second table.

and finally a picture of the ServiceModel schema:

[image]

from what I understood you can't implement ICollection of type ENUM and you have to wrap it in a class so basically you need an object to hold the ENUM with an ID and another Id that holds the userId.
The problem is that UserCredentialsModel table should hold an Id property of ServiceId coming from ServiceModel table.
because the class has a field of ICollection but when migrating it does nothing

Comment: _I am trying to implement an object that holds a type of ICollection<Enum> type._ - It looks like you are actually implementing an ICollection<ServiceModel>, which isn't an Enum. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, from what I understood you can't implement ICollection of type ENUM and you have to wrap it in a class so basicaly you need an object to hold the ENUM with an ID and another Id that holds the userId

Comment: The problem is that UserCredentialsModel table should hold an Id property of ServiceId coming from ServiceModel table

Comment: becuase the class has a field of ICollection<ServiceModel> but when migrating it does nothing

Comment: It (the UserCredentialsModel) doesn't have to have an ServiceId property because ServiceModel already contains a UserCredentialsModelUserId column. It is enough to configure the relationship. What do you mean by migrating? Are you trying to apply migrations on the database and are they failing? Or are you trying to insert data and won't that work?

Comment: Thank you, I see that the problem was with my tests.. the code I posted works fine.

Comment: Only one question, How do I retrieve all from ServicesModel where userId==userId ? Becuase when I try to do _context.ServiceModel.Where(i => i.UserId).First(); I dont see UserId with intelisense, I only see Service & ServiceId

Comment: I do not have this property in the object itself, it is created in the databse, shoud I create it in the obecect aswell?

Comment: That's because EF creates [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#foreign-key-shadow-properties) when it detects a relationship but doesn't detect any explicit foreign keys declared on the entity. If you do want to expose those as properties of your entity, you would indeed have to add them manually.